# Minor change in ansible playbook does not get updated in target host

Tags: nginx, docker, ansible

My playbook is (among other things) starting a docker container:

```
- name: Restart nginx container
  docker:
    name: nginx
    image: my-nginx
    state: started
    ports:
    - "{{ nginx_port }}:80"
    volumes:
    - "{{ host_socket }}:{{ container_socket }}"
```

This is correctly starting the container. But if I decide I need to run `nginx` in another port, and run again the playbook, the container is not restarted. It seems that `ansible` is happy with the container being up and running, but does not verify if the rest of parameters are right.

I see two options here:

1. force a restart whenever I run the playbook, no conditions asked, so that I make sure that the latest configuration is active. I do not like this because most of the time the parameters do not change.
2. force `ansible` to be more accurate and check all parameters, restarting the container if *whatever value* has changed. I am not sure there is such an option.

How can I tell `ansible` to be more accurate when checking the state of the container?

Answer (score 1):

The docker module is deprecated, I assume it must be one of its issue.

Did you try the [docker_container module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/docker_container_module.html)? You will need ansible > 2.1.0 but I think it's worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

> It seems that ansible is happy with the container being up and running, but does not verify if the rest of parameters are right.

Yes, because you specified `state: started`, and that's explicitly what that means:

> "started" asserts that the matching containers both exist and are running, but takes no action if any configuration has changed.

You probably want `reloaded` instead:

> "reloaded" (added in Ansible 1.9) asserts that all matching containers are running and restarts any that have any images or configuration out of date.